# Trying to post to two database tables from one form - Laravel 8

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-8

I am using Laravel 8 and trying to get an application form to post to two tables in my database

From my 2 database migration files:

```
public function up() {
    Schema::create('applicants', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('apptitle');
        $table->string('firstname');
        $table->string('middlename')->nullable();
        ...
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

```
public function up() {
    Schema::create('applications', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->integer('applicant_id'); 
        $table->integer('user_id');  
        $table->integer('loanAmount');
        $table->string('loanTerm');
        ...
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Models:

```
class Applicant extends Model {
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'applicants';
    protected $fillable = [
        'apptitle', 'firstname', 'middlename'...
    ];

    public function application() {
        return $this->hasOne(Application::class);
    }        
}
```

```
class Application extends Model {
    use HasFactory;
    protected $table = 'applications';
    protected $fillable = [
        'applicant_id',
        'user_id',
        'loanAmount',
        'loanTerm',  
        ...
    ];

    public function applicant() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Applicant::class);
    }
}
```

Controllers:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests\Applicants\CreateApplicantRequest;

class ApplicantsController extends Controller {
    ...
    public function store(CreateApplicantRequest $request) {
        $applicant = Applicant::create([
            'apptitle' => $request->apptitle,
            'firstname' => $request->firstname,
            'middlename' => $request->middlename,
            ...
        ]);
    }
```

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Application;
use App\Models\Applicant;
use App\Models\User;
use App\Http\Requests\Applications\CreateApplicationRequest;

class ApplicationsController extends Controller {
    ...
    public function store(CreateApplicationRequest $request) {
       $application = Application::create([
            'applicant_id' => $request->applicant_id,
            'user_id' => 'required',  
            'loanAmount' => 'required',
            'loanTerm' => 'required',
           ...
        ]);
    }
}
```

Requests:

```
public function rules() {
    return [
        'apptitle' => 'required',
        'firstname' => 'required',
        'middlename',
        ...
    ];
}
```

```
public function rules() {
    return [
        'applicant_id' => 'required',
        'user_id' => 'required',  
        'loanAmount' => 'required',
        'loanTerm' => 'required',
        ...
    ];
}
```

web.php

```
Route::get('applicants','ApplicantsController@store');
Route::resource('applications', 'ApplicationsController');
Route::get('applications/{application}', 'ApplicationsController@show');
```

I am continually getting errors: The applicant id field is required. (If I make this field nullable the form does successfully post all other fields to the database.)

This is my first big Laravel project so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Update:

I have gone through the answers provided and am still getting the same error.

I feel the main issue is - when the form is filled out the **applicant_id** field for the newly created Applicant is not being captured and added to the applications table?

Comment: Welcome to SO .. how your calling both controller ?

Comment: Can you check what is the value you're getting in your `$request->applicant_id`, because in your migrations `applicant_id` column is `not null`. And also please specify the table name in  models.

Comment: No value is being passed to applicant_id

Comment: Remove **use App\Http\Requests\Applicants\CreateApplicantRequest;** from your ApplicationsController.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally was able to get my form posting correctly to both databases - a big thank you to all those that have helped me in this journey.

This is my updated store function in my ApplicationsController:

```
public function store(CreateApplicationRequest $request, Applicant $applicant)
{            
    $applicant = Applicant::create([
        'apptitle' => $request->apptitle,
        'firstname' => $request->firstname,
        'middlename' => $request->middlename,
        ...
    ]);
    
    $application = $applicant->application()->create([
        'applicant_id' => $applicant->id,
        'user_id' => auth()->id(),
        'loanAmount' => $request->loanAmount,
        'loanTerm' => $request->loanTerm,
        ...
        ]); 
        
        

    // redirect the user

    return redirect(route('applications.index'));
}
```

I hope this answer helps someone else out!

Answer (score 2):

[You can store data from one form into 2 tables like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZjtXm.png)

Comment: Does this replace the separate database request files?

Answer (score 1):

Remove use App\Http\Requests\Applicants\CreateApplicantRequest; from your ApplicationsController and run the following cmd commands:

```
composer dump-autoload

php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear 
php artisan view:clear
php artisan route:clear
```

These commands clear all cache from your project.

Add nullable to your application migration applicant_id:

```
$table->integer('applicant_id')->nullable();
```

Comment: I tried this, still getting same result :-(

Comment: In your applicantion migration file make the applicant_id as nullable: $table->integer('applicant_id')->nullable();